# TensorFlow: How to fix ValueError: feed value of shape (50,2) which has shape (50,1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to define a graph that forsm a model for CBOW. Below is how I am defining my graph but I continue to get the following error: **ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 2) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(50, 1)'**

```
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, embedding_size])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder_with_default(1.0, shape=())

nce_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, batch_size], stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))

nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tf.convert_to_tensor(glove_embeddings_arr), input_data)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights, biases=nce_biases, labels=labels, inputs=tf.reduce_sum(embed, 1), num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1.0).minimize(loss)

accuracy=0

return input_data, labels, dropout_keep_prob, optimizer, accuracy, loss
```

Comment: This means that you are feeding an array of shape (50,2) in `labels` (aka. Placeholder_1:0) although you have defined it as being a tensor with shape (50,1). However, you did not provide the part of your code were you are feeding data in `labels`

Comment: so if I change it to labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 2]) it get this error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 100 and 50 for 'nce_loss/sub' (op: 'Sub') with in
put shapes: [100,1], [50,1]

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Depending on your actual need

Answer (score 2):

This means that you are feeding an array of shape (50,2) in `labels` (aka. `Placeholder_1:0`) in a part of your code you are not providing.

However, you have defined `labels` as being a tensor with shape (50,1):

```
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 2])
```

Thus, either you need to redefine it as a tensor of shape (50,2), either you need to change the shape of data you put in it. Depending on your needs...

Comment: so if I change it to labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 2]) it gets this error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 100 and 50 for 'nce_loss/sub' (op: 'Sub') with in
put shapes: [100,1], [50,1]

Comment: Not sure of what you want to do here, but you might want to set `num_true=2` in `tf.nn.nce_loss`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tf.nn.nce_loss`, each value `x_input` and `labels`, in general, are an index (`int32`, for instance). This code seems to be a skip-gram with two neighbors and batch size equal 50. The problem is that if you put , all batches need to have two neighbors. The most common is to set to 1 (and be cool instead of loss variation). Obviously, if this is the case (skip-gram), each word will have more than one label and you need to transpose the labels columns or reshape it.